# Django redirect from one page to another

Tags: django, http-redirect

I am working on a project in Django and I'm facing an issue while redirecting from one page to another on the click of a link. No matter what all I've tried, I end up having a url like:

`localhost:8080/page1/page2`

instead of moving from `localhost:8080/page1` to `localhost:8080/page2`

I've tried by using `HttpResponseRedirect(url)`

Comment: You need to make sure that `url` always starts with a slash: `"/page2"`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @DanielRoseman but I'm already doing that.

Comment: how are you creating `url`? using `reverse` or `reverse_lazy`? or are you constructing it in the template when rendering?

Comment: in the template @nkhumphreys

Comment: ok, and you are rendering a list of URLs in the template?  Have you inspected the rendered HTML to see what the URLs look like?  Are you using method based views or class based views in the backend?

Comment: The views are method based @nkhumphreys

Comment: Could you post the code snippet from your template that constructs the URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120433/discussion-between-nkhumphreys-and-venu-saini).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way is to use `{% url 'url-name' arg1 arg2 kwarg='foo' %}` in django template.
You shouldn't hardcode urls in your template but use url names.
More details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url

The equivalent in python code is `django.utls.reverse` which returns te absolute url or `django.shortcuts.redirect` which is equivalent to `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_name'))`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse

**EDIT #1**

Use database to pass items between views.

*models.py*

```
from django.db.models import Model

class Item(Model):
    # your model fields
```

*views.py*

```
def list_view(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    context = {'items': items}
    return render(request, 'list_template.html', context)

def details_view(request, item_id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    context = {'item': item}
    return render(request, 'details_template.html', context)
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/list/$', views.list_view, name='list')
    url(r'^/details/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.details_view, name='details'),
]
```

*list_template.html*

```
<!-- your html -->
<ul>
{% for item in items %}
    <li>
    <a href="{% url 'details' item.id %}">item number {{ item.id }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<!-- your html -->
```

`{% url ... %}` tag produces absolute url to pattern named "details" and substitute part of the address with function argument. In the addres, instead of `(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)`, you'll have item id eg. `/details/1/`. When you click the link, number `1` is grabbed by regex and passed to the function argument where you can take your Item from the database.

Comment: Thanks @warownia1 for your help. What I actually am trying to do is that I have a list of items with an `<a>` tag on each item. When any of the items is clicked, I need to redirect to a 'details' page where the details are specific to the particular item. I need to pass the item along. Any suggestions about that?

Comment: You can't pass python objects using GET requests, but you can pass item id or name and reconstruct the item or fetch it from the database in the details view. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @warownia1 I have just helped Venu in the Stackoverflow chat and pretty much gave the exact answer that you have typed in your edit.  To save repeating I have asked her to just mark yours as the correct answer :)

Comment: Okay, great. btw, I didn't know that stackoverflow does have a chat :p
Please mark the answer as correct and close the topic.

Comment: It was news to me as well, it popped up when the number of comments got too large :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem, but it took me a long time to figure out where it was coming from. I had discovered that there was a "/" missing from the href of the base HTML file before the url inclusion.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/loans/personal/                                                                                     http://127.0.0.1:8000/loans/personal/loans/business/                                                                                                                                            http://127.0.0.1:8000/loans/personal/loans/business/loans/gold/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35692365)